# how to split 16 bit binary string into two 8 bit binary string in c# console

Tags: c#

I have 1 fix binary number i.e:0110. I have two user input numbers which will be converted to binary with 6 bit. So now I have 16 bit binary frame. Now I want to split 16 bit frame into 2 8-bit binary frame and i dont know how to do that. Please help me. 
HERE is my code:

```
int num1, num2;
Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st number:");
num1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter 2nd number:");
num2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string bin1 = Convert.ToString(num1, 2).PadLeft(6, '0');
Console.WriteLine(bin1);
string bin2 = Convert.ToString(num2, 2).PadLeft(6, '0');
Console.WriteLine(bin2);
string bin3 = "0110";
string res = string.Concat(bin3, bin1, bin2);
Console.WriteLine(res);
string result = res;

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

OutPut of this code:

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Last line in the image is the 16 bit binary frame and i want to split that frame into two

Comment: If you want the result as a string, just use `Substring`. If you want the result as two numbers, I wouldn't use string representations at all. If you could add more detail to the question about what you're trying to do, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I just want the result in 2 8 bit binary frame. And please check the image i add

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean by "binary frame" but if you really just want the strings, `Substring` should be absolutely fine. Have you tried using that yet? If so, what happened? (I'd also urge you to show the content of that image as *text* in your question, given that there's nothing inherently graphical about it.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Thnxx it works!!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a question of implementing your own logic.

You can try this, it divides a string based on the count you give it, You'll supply it with 8, since you want 8-bit frames.

```
    public static string[] SplitBy(string str, int count)
    {
        var some = new string[str.Length/count];
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                string temp = str.Substring(i * 8, count);
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    some[i] = temp;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                break;
            }

        }
        return some;
    }
```

I left the exception handling for you.